# Using Linux Find and piping content to S3 bucket

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, find, command-line-interface

I am trying the following but getting errors. Has anyone used find with S3 copy before? Have not been able to find a good answer for this. The aws CP command works great with --recursive options, sync etc..However trying to see if its possible to do this. Documentation seems sketchy on answer for this.

```
find . -mtime -3 | aws s3 cp <find result> s3://<bucketname>
```

Comment: are you trying filter S3 files before copying the files from S3?

Comment: As you can see im not copying from S3, I am copying to S3. Filter isnt part of the question. Just need to know if its possible to use find in linux piped results to the S3 copy command

Answer (score 0):

You need to pipe the output stream to an S3 bucket object.

Example:

```
find . -mtime -3 | aws s3 cp - s3://<BUCKET_NAME>/<OBJECT_NAME>.txt
```

Comment: You reformatted but didnt answer the question. Not only that but the answer assumes explicit name for object when find is using directory search.

Comment: Im assuming nobody has done this before so Ill remove the question since the answers show confusion.

Comment: As per your question, it looks like you wanted the output of `find` command to put into S3 object. Hence the answer. Do you want to copy the output (read: `files`) of find command to S3 bucket ?